# signature page in Latex

Tags: latex

I intend to make signature page in the following two different and separate formats.

[image]

Currently the code is showing the person name on top and signature line at the bottom. I would like to get as shown in the attached image along with the date at the bottom right.

```
\newpage
\begin{center}{\Large\bf Signature Page}\end{center}
\vspace{0.3cm}

sometext here sometext heresometext heresometext heresometext heresometext heresometext heresometext heresometext heresometext heresometext heresometext heresometext heresometext heresometext heresometext heresometext heresometext heresometext heresometext heresometext heresometext heresometext heresometext here.

\vfill
\newcommand{\namesigdate}[2][5cm]{%
\begin{minipage}{#1}
    #2 \vspace{1.5cm}\hrule\smallskip
\end{minipage}
}

\noindent \namesigdate{Mr.X} \ \hfill \namesigdate[5cm]{Mr.Y} 
\\
\\
\vspace{1.5cm}\smallskip \\ \\ 
\noindent \namesigdate{Mr.XY} \ \hfill \namesigdate[5cm]{Mr.YY}
\\
\\
Date 2019May05
\\
```

Comment: for the second format I couldnt figure out how to do

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Some notes:

- `\bf` is deprecated. Consider `\textbf` and `\bfseries` instead.
- If "Signature Page" should be one of your sections, you should consider use `\section` and do some settings for section using `titlesec`.

#### Code for the first layout

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newcommand\signature[2]{% Name; Department
\noindent\begin{minipage}{5cm}
    \noindent\vspace{3cm}\par
    \noindent\rule{5cm}{1pt}\par
    \noindent\textbf{#1}\par
    \noindent#2%
\end{minipage}}
\newcommand\insertdate[1][\today]{\vfill\begin{flushright}#1\end{flushright}}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
% This is not a good practice, but as I don't know "Signature Page" is a section 
% or not, I have no alternatives
\Large\bfseries Signature Page
\end{center}
\lipsum[1]

\signature{Mr. A}{ABC Department}\hfill\signature{Mr. B}{DEF Department}

\signature{Mr. C}{ABC Department}\hfill\signature{Mr. D}{DEF Department}

\signature{Mr. E}{ABC Department}\hfill\signature{Mr. F}{DEF Department}

\insertdate[May 5, 2019] % Default it will print today
\end{document}
```

#### Code for the second layout

A little change and you will get the second one.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newcommand\signature[2]{% Name; Department
\begin{center}\begin{minipage}{5cm}
    \centering
    \vspace{3cm}\par
    \rule{5cm}{1pt}\par
    \textbf{#1}\par
    #2%
\end{minipage}\end{center}}
\newcommand\insertdate[1][\today]{\vfill\begin{flushright}#1\end{flushright}}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
% This is not a good practice, but as I don't know "Signature Page" is a section 
% or not, I have no alternatives
\Large\bfseries Signature Page
\end{center}
\lipsum[1]

\signature{Mr. A}{ABC Department}

\signature{Mr. C}{ABC Department}

\signature{Mr. E}{ABC Department}

\insertdate[May 5, 2019] % Default it will print today
\end{document}
```

Happy TeXing! And consider going to [TeX.SE](https://tex.stackexchange.com) for more experienced LaTeX users.